# Lessons and Student Marks table - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a table of lessons and student marks.

Lessons;

```
ID   | Lesson_Name | Teacher_Name
---------------------------------
1    | Maths       |   Teacher1
2    | Literature  |   Teacher2
3    | Psychology  |   Teacher3
4    | Law         |   Teacher4
```

Student_Marks;

```
ID   | LessonID | Student ID | Mark
---------------------------------
1    | 1        |   1        | 100
2    | 1        |   2        | 70
3    | 2        |   1        | 80
4    | 3        |   2        | 30
5    | 2        |   3        | 60
```

Students;

```
ID   | Student
---------------------------------
1    | John
2    | Ashley
3    | Geroge
4    | Steve
```

I want a table like this one;

```
Lesson      | Teacher  | Student1 | Student2 | Student3
-------------------------------------------------------
Maths       | Teacher1 |  100     | 70       | 60   
Literature  | Teacher2 |  70      | 40       | 
Psychology  | Teacher3 |          | 50       | 30 
Law         | Teacher4 |  30      | 60       |
```

Currently I get all data with the query below and parsing them with PHP to build the table.

```
SELECT
    l.id,l.lesson_id,l.lesson_name,l.teacher_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', sm.studentid, sm.studentmark) SEPARATOR ',') as students
FROM lessons l
LEFT JOIN student_marks sm ON l.lesson_id = sm.lesson_id
GROUP BY l.lesson_id
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: What issue you have with this?

Comment: Search for "*dynamic MySQL PIVOT*".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)